# Discord Webhooks and JSON construct limits for non-OAuth apps

Tags: discord

I'm trying to clarify whether or not it's possible to `POST` JSON to a Discord channel webhook, without requiring a fully fledged OAuth authenticated app, and have it display more than a single line of text.

I can successfully send data to the webhook endpoint (using PowerShell), but it will ignore any fields other than 'content'. I was hoping to be able to post an [`Embed object`](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object), which comes from the [Execute Webhook](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) documentation, but it just seems to ignore it.

The JSON is like so:

```
{
  "content": "Hi. I'm a robot.",
  "embed": {
    "title":"This is a title",
    "type":"Rich",
    "description":"This is a description",
    "url":"http://www.google.com",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name":"field1",
            "value": "some value",
            "inline": "true"
        },
        {
            "name":"field2",
            "value": "another value",
            "inline": "true"
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

Thank you.